# How To Prepend String Only If Match Found Between Two Files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm working on a couple files that contain urls. I have tried using sed, cut and grep, but I'm really unsure of how to approach this. If you could just get me moving in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

File 1:

```
https://example1.com
http://example2.com
```

File 2:

```
example1.com/example1-is-https-domain/
example1.com/need-https-in-front/
example1.com/match-me-to-https/
example1.com/example-https-not-http/
example2.com/im-an-http-domain/
example2.com/must-match-to-example2/
example2.com/path-of-http/
example2.com/http-domain-not-https/
example3.com/this-should-not-match/
example3.com/this-page-is-not-required/
```

Desired output:

```
https://example1.com/example1-is-https-domain/
https://example1.com/need-https-in-front/
https://example1.com/match-me-to-https/
https://example1.com/example-https-not-http/
http://example2.com/im-an-http-domain/
http://example2.com/must-match-to-example2/
http://example2.com/path-of-http/
http://example2.com/http-domain-not-https/
```

My approach:

I'm thinking I can use grep with the option to match after '//' and then would need to use another command to paste together what is found? Here's where I'm struggling a bit. Any help is very much appreciated.

Summary:

I'm really trying to prepend the correct http or https to the matching domain between File 1 and 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"}NR==FNR{k[$3]=$0;next}$1 in k{$1=k[$1];print}'
```

I think it makes the job, but I don't have an awk right here to test it.

It creates a dictionary with the selected domains with the first file (NR==FNR), and for the second file it looks the domain in the created dictionary, if exists, then it replace the domain name with the full record from file 1 and then print all

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used awk with two files before. Where do I insert my inputs in this code?

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"}NR==FNR{k[$3]=$0;next}$1 in k{$1=k[$1];print}' File1.txt File2.txt

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. Nice way to to specify the third '/', works great for me. Please upvote the question too. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's#.*//(.*)#s,^\1,&,p#' file1 | sed -nf - file2
```

Generate a sed script from `file1` and apply it to `file2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). I see answers for sed and awk, so here's one in pure bash (4+) to complete the set.

In bash alone, with no external tools at all, you could do something like this:

```
# Populate an associative array with the domain/method map
declare -A s=()
while IFS=/ read -a a; do
  s["${a[2]}"]="${a[0]}"
done < file1

# Step through the URL list, printing array values based on the domain
while IFS=/ read d p; do
  [[ ${s[$d]+z} ]] && printf '%s//%s/%s\n' "${s[$d]}" "$d" "$p"
done < file2
```

This obviously is neither as sexy as kcoder's awk solution, nor as beautifully cryptic as potong's sed-script-that-writes-a-sed-script, but it should produce just about the same results.